# I am building an ensemble deep learning model which takes two inputs, when I concatenate it gives an error

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_features,n_features)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

mode2 = Sequential()
mode2.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)))
mode2.add(Dropout(0.2))
mode2.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
mode2.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax'))
mode2.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

merged = concatenate([model, mode2], axis=-1)
```

I am building an ensemble deep learning model which takes two inputs when I concatenate it gives an error.

Comment: ValueError: Layer concatenate_4 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>. Full input: [<keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x000000CBD673F7B8>, <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x000000CBD680B9E8>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.

Comment: and importing all necessary libraries, need help regrading this

Comment: Include the error in the question, as well as what you are expecting to happen.